# magento remove the cookie popup block based on condition not working

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I have to dsiplay the cookie restriction popup block of magento based on a condition.

ie) if Condition is true, the block should display , else not.

I have tried like below in the CookieNotice.php , but im not able to get how to remove the entire block, if condition is not satisfied.

**\app\code\core\Mage\Page\Block\Html\CookieNotice.php**

```
class Mage_Page_Block_Html_CookieNotice extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
public function getCookieRestrictionBlockContent()
{
    $remoteAddr = Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr(true); 
   $info = geoip_record_by_name($remoteAddr);
   $countrycode = $info['country_code'];  //IN

   $allowed = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/country/eu_countries'); //AT,BE,BG,CY,CZ,DK,EE,FI,FR,DE,GR,HU,IE,IT,LV,LT,LU,MT,NL,PL,PT,RO,SK,SI,ES,SE,GB

   if(in_array($countrycode, $allowed)){
        echo 'match found';

        $blockIdentifier = Mage::helper('core/cookie')->getCookieRestrictionNoticeCmsBlockIdentifier();
        $block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($blockIdentifier, 'identifier');
        $html = '';
        if ($block->getIsActive()) {
            /* @var $helper Mage_Cms_Helper_Data */
            $helper = Mage::helper('cms');
            $processor = $helper->getBlockTemplateProcessor();
            $html = $processor->filter($block->getContent());
        }
        return $html;
   }
   else{
        // Here still the pop block appears
         echo 'No match found';
     }

   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a heads up. You can never 100% trust localization through IP. People can be behind proxies, surf through VPN etc. If this is to comply with GDPR or some other legal requirement, then you should let everyone see it, just to make sure (the laws usually don't care about where the users IP is registered, only where the user physically is located).

Comment: Yes i have to do this complying GDPR... could you please help on this

Comment: Like I said, just show it to everyone. You can't 100% know where the request comes from in all situations and if you miss it for someone in EU, it can be expensive.

Comment: hi @MagnusEriksson, could you please show it in code how to show the cookie popup for all users in EU and with what change i have to do

Comment: Hi @MagnusEriksson, have updated the question..im left with how to get the GDPR cookie in a right way..